# Convolution of a pdf $f$ with a Gaussian $g$: distance between $g\ast f$ and $g$?

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, convolution

I have been looking for references on the following matter: let $f$ be the pdf of any real-value random variable ($f$ is not necessarily continuous wrt Lebesgue measure), and $g=g_{\mu,\sigma}$ be a Gaussian pdf. Writing $d_{\rm TV}$ for the total variation distance and $\ast$ for the convolution, is there anything that can be said between $d_{\rm TV}(f,g)$ and $d_{\rm TV}(g\ast f,g)$?

In particular, is there any result of the form 
$$
d_{\rm TV}(g\ast f,g) \leq \alpha\cdot d_{\rm TV}(f,g)^\beta
$$
for some universal constants $\alpha,\beta >0$?

(if not, what would be a sufficient assumption on $f$? E.g., $f = a\mu + (1-a)\nu$ with $a > 0$ and $\mu$ a measure continuous wrt Lebesgue — would that be enough?)

If this is a straightforward exercise or a known and simple result (or, on the contrary, easily seen to be false), can someone point me towards either a proof of it, or a way/hint to prove it, or anything of that sort?

**Edit:** in case this could be easier (or hold while the above does not(?)), I am also interested in the same sort of result, but with the Earthmover's Distance (Wasserstein metric) instead of the more stringent total variation.

Comment: If $f=g$ then $d_{\mathrm TV}(f,g)=0\ne d_{\mathrm TV}(g\ast f,g)$ hence the inequalities you are asking about seem unlikely. Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Erm. Thanks! So much for wishful thinking...

Answer (score 3):

For the Wasserstein distance, perhaps Lemma 7.1.10 in the book ``Gradient Flows in Metric Spaces and the Space of Probability Measures'' by Ambrosio, Gigli, and Savaré is what you are looking for.

Comment: Without access to the text, this is not a helpful answer.  It would be much better if you could summarize the result (at least state with appropriate definitions) the lemma you refer to...

Comment: A friendly welcome to Math.SE from your (at least occasionally) friendly moderator. I'm sure this answer can be turned into something helpful, and your intentions are clearly good. However, it may well be that not all users have access to any given book. Therefore we seek to keep the posts as self-contained as possible. It would be best that you write the contents of that Lemma here. Click the edit-button under your post, and TeX it in. TeX is handled by MathJax here. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for instructions.

Comment: Why the downvote? I have found the correct reference in the lemma, which is really useful. Thank you!